# send mail to Gmail account

Tags: java, http, sockets, smtp, gmail

I am sending mail from my Java app to Gmail Account. I had used the Java Mail API and it worked fine. But is it possible to send an e-mail without using the mail API in java?

I mean just by using sockets:

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    int port = 465;
    String from = "sh2rpzain@gmail.com";
    String toAddr = "sharpzian@gmail.com";


    Socket servSocket = new Socket(host, port);
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(servSocket.getOutputStream());
    DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(servSocket.getInputStream());

    if (servSocket != null && os != null && is != null) {
      os.writeBytes("HELO\r\n");
      os.writeBytes("MAIL From:" + from + " \r\n");
      os.writeBytes("RCPT To:" + toAddr + "\r\n");
      os.writeBytes("DATA\r\n");
      os.writeBytes("X-Mailer: Java\r\n");
      os.writeBytes("DATE: " + DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL, 
                                   Locale.US).format(new Date()) + "\r\n");
      os.writeBytes("From:" + from + "\r\n");
      os.writeBytes("To:" + toAddr + "\r\n");
    }

    os.writeBytes("Subject:\r\n");
    os.writeBytes("body\r\n");
    os.writeBytes("\r\n.\r\n");
    os.writeBytes("QUIT\r\n");
    String responseline;
    while ((responseline = is.readUTF()) != null) { 
      if (responseline.indexOf("Ok") != -1)
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

But it is not working, it doesn't send out the mail. Can anyone tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: Try to close the socket at the end, I had a bug with this some time ago.

Comment: It doesnt show any error but the mail is not trsnsferred

Comment: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. ei16sm26532474wbb.21

Comment: Please try to solve problems with answers *here* rather than immediately adding another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good example:

```
public class SMTPDemo {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException,
      UnknownHostException {
    String msgFile = "file.txt";
    String from = "java2s@java2s.com";
    String to = "yourEmail@yourServer.com";
    String mailHost = "yourHost";
    SMTP mail = new SMTP(mailHost);
    if (mail != null) {
      if (mail.send(new FileReader(msgFile), from, to)) {
        System.out.println("Mail sent.");
      } else {
        System.out.println("Connect to SMTP server failed!");
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Done.");
  }

  static class SMTP {
    private final static int SMTP_PORT = 25;

    InetAddress mailHost;

    InetAddress localhost;

    BufferedReader in;

    PrintWriter out;

    public SMTP(String host) throws UnknownHostException {
      mailHost = InetAddress.getByName(host);
      localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
      System.out.println("mailhost = " + mailHost);
      System.out.println("localhost= " + localhost);
      System.out.println("SMTP constructor done\n");
    }

    public boolean send(FileReader msgFileReader, String from, String to)
        throws IOException {
      Socket smtpPipe;
      InputStream inn;
      OutputStream outt;
      BufferedReader msg;
      msg = new BufferedReader(msgFileReader);
      smtpPipe = new Socket(mailHost, SMTP_PORT);
      if (smtpPipe == null) {
        return false;
      }
      inn = smtpPipe.getInputStream();
      outt = smtpPipe.getOutputStream();
      in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inn));
      out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outt), true);
      if (inn == null || outt == null) {
        System.out.println("Failed to open streams to socket.");
        return false;
      }
      String initialID = in.readLine();
      System.out.println(initialID);
      System.out.println("HELO " + localhost.getHostName());
      out.println("HELO " + localhost.getHostName());
      String welcome = in.readLine();
      System.out.println(welcome);
      System.out.println("MAIL From:<" + from + ">");
      out.println("MAIL From:<" + from + ">");
      String senderOK = in.readLine();
      System.out.println(senderOK);
      System.out.println("RCPT TO:<" + to + ">");
      out.println("RCPT TO:<" + to + ">");
      String recipientOK = in.readLine();
      System.out.println(recipientOK);
      System.out.println("DATA");
      out.println("DATA");
      String line;
      while ((line = msg.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(line);
      }
      System.out.println(".");
      out.println(".");
      String acceptedOK = in.readLine();
      System.out.println(acceptedOK);
      System.out.println("QUIT");
      out.println("QUIT");
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

-> http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/SendingMailUsingSockets.htm

Comment: what is the logic of msgfile variable?

Comment: There is the message located which will be send.

Comment: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. ei16sm26532474wbb.21

Comment: It looks like Google added some restrictions where you need STARTTLS, however I can't find any information on this anywhere. You almost have to use JavaMail now... I'm trying to use sockets to do this same thing today, and cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dynamic IP you are probably not able to send messages to Googlemail.

Answer (score 0):

GMail doesn't allow non-secure mail transfer. You need to make an SSL/TLS connection in your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Google only allows encrypted connections. That's actually a good thing, in my opinion.

But if you must send your mails in plaintext, you can enable it on your [Account Page](http://mail.google.com/mail/#settings/accounts) under settings.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a secure connection, use SSLSocket instead of Socket, like this:

```
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) ((SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()).createSocket(InetAddress.getByName("smtp.gmail.com"), 465);
```