# Sending Email using Java Sockets

Tags: java, email, sockets, gmail

I am trying to send Email using Java Sockets but cannot seem to send the Email
(I am not using mail API of Java, I just want to use sockets to send Email).Please tell me where I am doing wrong and modify the code...I will be glad of any help...Thanks

Below is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
class MailingClient {

     public void smtp(String command) throws UnknownHostException, IOException { 

         Socket socket=new Socket("smtp.gmail.com",465);

         BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
         br.readLine();

         OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
         os.write(command.getBytes());
         smtp("HELLO " + "receiver@gmail.com");
         smtp("MAIL FROM: "+ "sender@gmail.com");
         smtp("DATA");
         smtp("yourContent");

  }
  public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
    {


        MailingClient c=new MailingClient();
        c.smtp("HELO");


    }
}
```

Comment: Is this your classmate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703059/send-mail-to-gmail-account This very same question is asked before today.

Comment: I have to agree.  This sounds like a homework question.

Comment: Its not homework ,Just for research purpose...

Comment: What you are doing wrong is trying to write it all yourself when it's already written. There is no point to this. JavaMail costs nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this should work, you 'just' have to implement the whole [SMTP protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) yourself. An introduction is available on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol). I'd really use a library for this.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you should use a library for this. If this is really a gmail account you need to authenticate yourself because gmail doesn't allow anonymous smtp. I don't know the java details for sockets, but in general you should do more with sockets than just create one. unix network programming part I covers the use of sockets. i.e. the mailserver sends an answer to your requests which you could also read from your socket pair.